# What is the difference between SQl Server and SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

What is the main difference between SQL SERVER and SQL AZURE, What is the advantage of SQL Azure

Comment: This is sort of apples to oranges.  SQL Azure is the version of SQL Server which would run in the Azure cloud environment (called RDS in AWS lingo).  So, one is a cloud based version of the other.

Comment: Is SQL Azure supports all the features,keywords in SQL Server

Comment: I don't know, but you should review Microsoft's documentation yourself to learn about this, unless you have an actual focused question to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2016/07/15/how-should-i-compare-azure-sql-database-paas-to-sql-server-running-on-a-azure-vm-iaas/) article you will find how they compare on topics like features, upgrades, limitations, TCO, business continuity, licensing, performance, security, data transfer and costs. SQL Azure has now more security features than the article show like row-level security, dynamic data masking, auditing, encryption, threat detection, and SQL Vulnerability Assessment as you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview).

About the Transact-SQL differences of Azure SQL Database compared with SQL Server you will find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information). Some of the most important differences are you cannot rely db_id(), you cannot use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS, linked servers are not available, cross database queries are allowed via elastic queries, some system stored procedures not supported, USE is not supported, four-part names not supported.